# Can't upload manuscript to International Journal of Information Security

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, bibtex, pdftex

I am submitting a paper to International Journal of Information Security for the first time. When I try to upload the tex file it shows me the error, while going through the preview, instead of the paper. Please help me to understand what is the meaning of this error.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.4.4)  26 JUN 2018 06:54 entering extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled. **./main-final.tex (./main-final.tex LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded. (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ieeeconf/IEEEconf.cls Document Class: IEEEconf 2009/04/05 v1.4 IEEE Computer Society 8.5x11" conferen ce proceedings (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count79 \c@section=\count80 \c@subsection=\count81 \c@subsubsection=\count82 \c@paragraph=\count83 \c@subparagraph=\count84 \c@figure=\count85 \c@table=\count86 \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42 \bibindent=\dimen102 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC) \KV@toks@=\toks14 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO) Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected. ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO) Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected. ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional ) \Gm@cnth=\count87 \Gm@cntv=\count88 \c@Gm@tempcnt=\count89 \Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103 \Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104 \Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105 \Gm@even@mp=\dimen106 \Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107 \Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108 \Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109 \Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110 
Manuscript Click here to download Manuscript main-final.tex Click here to view linked References
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathptmx.sty Package: mathptmx 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a Times w/ Math, improved (SPQR, WaS)  LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 28. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/ztmcm/m/n on input line 28. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ztmcm/m/n on input line 28. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 29. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal' (Font)                  OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/ztmcm/m/it on input line 29. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold' (Font)                  OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/ztmcm/m/it on input line 29. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 30. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal' (Font)                  OMS/cmsy/m/n --> OMS/ztmcm/m/n on input line 30. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold' (Font)                  OMS/cmsy/b/n --> OMS/ztmcm/m/n on input line 30. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 31. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal' (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/ztmcm/m/n on input line 31. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold' (Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/ztmcm/m/n on input line 31. \symbold=\mathgroup4 \symitalic=\mathgroup5 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 34. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 34. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> OT1/ptm/bx/n on input line 34. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 35. LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold' (Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> OT1/ptm/m/it on input line 35. LaTeX Info: Redefining \hbar on input line 50. ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty Package: helvet 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS)  ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/courier.sty Package: courier 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS)  ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty Package: array 2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi) \col@sep=\dimen111 \extrarowheight=\dimen112 \NC@list=\toks16 \extratabsurround=\skip43 \backup@length=\skip44 
) \ieee@author@width=\skip45 (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty Package: titlesec 2016/03/21 v2.10.2 Sectioning titles \ttl@box=\box26 \beforetitleunit=\skip46 \aftertitleunit=\skip47 \ttl@plus=\dimen113 \ttl@minus=\dimen114 \ttl@toksa=\toks17 \titlewidth=\dimen115 \titlewidthlast=\dimen116 \titlewidthfirst=\dimen117 )) ! Undefined control sequence. l.10 \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                                                                % This comman... The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. 

! Undefined control sequence. l.13 \overrideIEEEmargins                           The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. 

(c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO) \bibhang=\skip48 \bibsep=\skip49 LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694. \c@NAT@ctr=\count90 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty Package: amsmath 2016/03/10 v2.15b AMS math features \@mathmargin=\skip50 For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option. (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions \@emptytoks=\toks18 \ex@=\dimen118 )) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols \pmbraise@=\dimen119 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names 
) \inf@bad=\count91 LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 199. \uproot@=\count92 \leftroot@=\count93 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 297. \classnum@=\count94 \DOTSCASE@=\count95 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 394. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 397. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 518. \Mathstrutbox@=\box27 \strutbox@=\box28 \big@size=\dimen120 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 634. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 635. \macc@depth=\count96 \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count97 \dotsspace@=\muskip10 \c@parentequation=\count98 \dspbrk@lvl=\count99 \tag@help=\toks19 \row@=\count100 \column@=\count101 \maxfields@=\count102 \andhelp@=\toks20 \eqnshift@=\dimen121 \alignsep@=\dimen122 \tagshift@=\dimen123 \tagwidth@=\dimen124 \totwidth@=\dimen125 \lineht@=\dimen126 \@envbody=\toks21 \multlinegap=\skip51 \multlinetaggap=\skip52 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks22 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2739. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2740. ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty Package: tabularx 2016/02/03 v2.11 `tabularx' package (DPC) \TX@col@width=\dimen127 \TX@old@table=\dimen128 \TX@old@col=\dimen129 \TX@target=\dimen130 \TX@delta=\dimen131 \TX@cols=\count103 \TX@ftn=\toks23 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty Package: graphics 2016/01/03 v1.0q Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC) ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg 
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live ) Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 95. (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO) ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO) ) \Gread@gobject=\count104 )) \Gin@req@height=\dimen132 \Gin@req@width=\dimen133 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support \symAMSa=\mathgroup6 \symAMSb=\mathgroup7 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106. ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/enumerate.sty Package: enumerate 2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC) \@enLab=\toks24 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/newlfont.sty Package: newlfont 1998/08/17 v2.2m Standard LaTeX package LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 57. (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latexsym.sty Package: latexsym 1998/08/17 v2.2e Standard LaTeX package (lasy symbols) \symlasy=\mathgroup8 LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `lasy' in version `bold' (Font)                  U/lasy/m/n --> U/lasy/b/n on input line 52. )) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty Package: algorithm 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating enviro nment (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty Package: float 2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL) \c@float@type=\count105 \float@exts=\toks25 \float@box=\box29 \@float@everytoks=\toks26 \@floatcapt=\box30 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC) ) \@float@every@algorithm=\toks27 \c@algorithm=\count106 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty Package: algpseudocode  
(c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.sty Package: algorithmicx 2005/04/27 v1.2 Algorithmicx Document Style algorithmicx 1.2 - a greatly improved `algorithmic' style \c@ALG@line=\count107 \c@ALG@rem=\count108 \c@ALG@nested=\count109 \ALG@tlm=\skip53 \ALG@thistlm=\skip54 \c@ALG@Lnr=\count110 \c@ALG@blocknr=\count111 \c@ALG@storecount=\count112 \c@ALG@tmpcounter=\count113 \ALG@tmplength=\skip55 ) Document Style - pseudocode environments for use with the `algorithmicx' style ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/placeins/placeins.sty Package: placeins 2005/04/18  v 2.2 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty \lst@mode=\count114 \lst@gtempboxa=\box31 \lst@token=\toks28 \lst@length=\count115 \lst@currlwidth=\dimen134 \lst@column=\count116 \lst@pos=\count117 \lst@lostspace=\dimen135 \lst@width=\dimen136 \lst@newlines=\count118 \lst@lineno=\count119 \lst@maxwidth=\dimen137 (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty File: lstmisc.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz) \c@lstnumber=\count120 \lst@skipnumbers=\count121 \lst@framebox=\box32 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg File: listings.cfg 2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration )) Package: listings 2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive ) Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225. Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337. Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341. Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353. Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355. Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356. 
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357. Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358. Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359. Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360. ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty File: lstlang1.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 listings language file ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty File: lstlang1.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 listings language file ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty File: lstmisc.sty 2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz) ) 

LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):     [conference]. 

(./main-final.aux 

LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined. 


LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined. 


LaTeX Warning: Label `' multiply defined. 

) \openout1 = `main-final.aux'. 

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 88. LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ptm on input line 88. (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd File: ot1ptm.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm. ) *geometry* driver: auto-detecting *geometry* detected driver: pdftex *geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result: * driver: pdftex * paper: letterpaper * layout: <same size as paper> 
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt) * modes:  * h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.27pt, 469.75499pt, 72.27pt) * v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 641.39624pt, 81.30376pt) * \paperwidth=614.295pt * \paperheight=794.96999pt * \textwidth=469.75499pt * \textheight=641.39624pt * \oddsidemargin=0.00002pt * \evensidemargin=0.00002pt * \topmargin=0.0pt * \headheight=0.0pt * \headsep=0.0pt * \topskip=10.0pt * \footskip=0.0pt * \marginparwidth=4.0pt * \marginparsep=10.0pt * \columnsep=27.10124pt * \skip\footins=9.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt * \hoffset=0.0pt * \voffset=0.0pt * \mag=1000 * \@twocolumntrue * \@twosidefalse * \@mparswitchfalse * \@reversemarginfalse * (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt) 

(c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] \scratchcounter=\count122 \scratchdimen=\dimen138 \scratchbox=\box33 \nofMPsegments=\count123 \nofMParguments=\count124 \everyMPshowfont=\toks29 \MPscratchCnt=\count125 \MPscratchDim=\dimen139 \MPnumerator=\count126 \makeMPintoPDFobject=\count127 \everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks30 ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO) Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected. ) Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected. Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available. Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available. Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found. ) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty 
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO) )) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO) (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO) Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded. (etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or (etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded. (etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier. ))) Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list: (grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps] (grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452. (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv e )) \c@lstlisting=\count128 LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <10> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 92. LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <14> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 92. LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <17.28> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 92. LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+ztmcm on input line 92 . (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ztmcm.fd File: ot1ztmcm.fd 2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OT1/ztmcm. ) LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+ztmcm on input line 92 . (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlztmcm.fd File: omlztmcm.fd 2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OML/ztmcm. ) 
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+ztmcm on input line 92 . (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsztmcm.fd File: omsztmcm.fd 2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMS/ztmcm. ) LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+ztmcm on input line 92 . (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxztmcm.fd File: omxztmcm.fd 2000/01/03 Fontinst v1.801 font definitions for OMX/ztmcm. ) LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <12> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 92. LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <9> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 92. LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 92. LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+lasy on input line 92. (c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions ) Underfull \hbox (badness 2512) in paragraph at lines 112--113 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Most web-sites and ap-pli-ca-tions use pass-word  [] 


Underfull \hbox (badness 3612) in paragraph at lines 114--116 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 It is also straight-for-ward to tar-get pass-word  [] 

[1{c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} 


] LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <11> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 119. 

Underfull \hbox (badness 7740) in paragraph at lines 126--128 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Most web-sites im-ple-ment pass-word strength  [] 

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+ptm on input line 129. 

(c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omsptm.fd File: omsptm.fd  
) LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/ptm/m/n' in size <10> not available (Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 129. 

Underfull \hbox (badness 1629) in paragraph at lines 134--135 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Various pass-word hash func-tions like PKDF2,  [] 

Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <1.eps> (epstopdf)                    date: 2018-06-26 06:54:02 (epstopdf)                    size: 903070 bytes (epstopdf)             Output file: <1-eps-converted-to.pdf> (epstopdf)                    date: 2018-06-26 06:54:07 (epstopdf)                    size: 19754 bytes (epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=1-eps-convertedto.pdf 1.e ps> (epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 146. Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate. <1-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=9, 946.53625pt x 264.99pt> File: 1-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf) <use 1-eps-converted-to.pdf> Package pdftex.def Info: 1-eps-converted-to.pdf used on input line 146. (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 221.32687pt x 61.9613pt. LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+phv on input line 147. 

(c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd File: ot1phv.fd 2001/06/04 scalable font definitions for OT1/phv. ) LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/phv/bx/n' in size <10> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/phv/b/n' tried instead on input line 147. [2 <./1-eps-converted-to.pdf>] Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Block2.eps> (epstopdf)                    date: 2018-06-26 06:54:02 (epstopdf)                    size: 661070 bytes (epstopdf)             Output file: <Block2-eps-converted-to.pdf> (epstopdf)                    date: 2018-06-26 06:54:09 (epstopdf)                    size: 12770 bytes (epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=Block2-epsconverted-to.pd f Block2.eps> (epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 159. Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate. <Block2-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=20, 384.43625pt x 158.5925pt> File: Block2-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf) <use Block2-eps-converted-to.pdf> Package pdftex.def Info: Block2-eps-converted-to.pdf used on input line 159. (pdftex.def)             Requested size: 221.32687pt x 91.30612pt. 

Underfull \hbox (badness 1609) in paragraph at lines 169--170 
\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 In this sec-tion, an al-go-rithm for gen-er-at-ing pass-  [] 


Underfull \hbox (badness 6268) in paragraph at lines 169--170 \OT1/ptm/m/n/10 word pol-icy is given. There are four mod-  [] 

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <7.4> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 173. LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/ptm/bx/n' in size <6> not available (Font)              Font shape `OT1/ptm/b/n' tried instead on input line 173. 

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [] 

LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+pcr on input line 212. 

(c:/TeXLive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1pcr.fd File: ot1pcr.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr. ) Underfull \hbox (badness 1107) in paragraph at lines 225--225 |[]\OT1/ptm/b/n/11 Pseudo-code for check-ing uni-for-mity of  [] 


Underfull \hbox (badness 4181) in paragraph at lines 230--232 []\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 pro-ce-dure $\OML/ztmcm/m/it/10 check[]uniformity[]alphabets$ \OT1/ptm/m/n/10 (\OT1/ptm/b/n/10 For al-  [] 


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [] 

[3 <./Block2-eps-converted-to.pdf>] Underfull \hbox (badness 1024) in paragraph at lines 262--263 \OT1/ptm/m/n/10 In the end, af-ter check-ing uni-for-mity if the value  [] 


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [] 


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 339--339 []|\OT1/ptm/m/n/8 variable that stores the  [] 


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 339--339 []|\OT1/ptm/m/n/8 variable that stores the  [] 



Underfull \vbox (badness 1454) has occurred while \output is active [] 

[4] Underfull \vbox (badness 4060) has occurred while \output is active [] 

[5] Underfull \hbox (badness 1888) in paragraph at lines 422--423 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Almeshekah, M.H., Gutier-rez, C.N., Atal-lah,  [] 

Missing character: There is no Ã in font ptmr7t! Missing character: There is no ¼ in font ptmr7t! Missing character: There is no Ã in font ptmr7t! Missing character: There is no ¼ in font ptmr7t! 

Underfull \hbox (badness 1137) in paragraph at lines 446--447 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Kelley, P.G., Ko-man-duri, S., Mazurek, M.L.,  [] 


Underfull \hbox (badness 2856) in paragraph at lines 452--453 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Moore, G.E.: Progress in dig-i-tal in-te-grated  [] 

Missing character: There is no â in font ptmr7t! Missing character: There is no € in font ptmr7t! Missing character: There is no “ in font ptmr7t! [6] Missing character: There is no Ä in font ptmr7t! Missing character: There is no ± in font ptmr7t! 

Underfull \hbox (badness 3271) in paragraph at lines 466--467 []\OT1/ptm/m/n/10 Tatl, E.I.: Crack-ing more pass-word hashes  [] 

[7] (./main-final.aux) 

LaTeX Warning: There were multiply-defined labels. 

 )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  6409 strings out of 493027  88447 string characters out of 6137679  197304 words of memory out of 5000000  9775 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000  52134 words of font info for 123 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  38i,18n,58p,1479b,375s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s {c:/TeXLive/2015/texmfdist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc}<c:/TeXLive/2015/texm 
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
```

Here is the preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out
%\usepackage{svjour}                                                     % if you need a4paper
%\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4
                                                         % paper

\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only
                                                          % needed if you want to
                                                          % use the \thanks command
\overrideIEEEmargins
% See the \addtolength command later in the file to balance the column lengths
% on the last page of the document

\makeatletter
\let\NAT@parse\undefined
\makeatother
%\usepackage[sorting=anyt,style=alphabetic,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear,sort,numbers]{natbib}
%\bibliographystyle{apa}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\lstset { %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\vars}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\func}{\textrm}
\let\oldReturn\Return
\renewcommand{\Return}{\State\oldReturn}
```

Comment: You're getting several warning messages, and two error messages. The latter concern the macros `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` and `\overrideIEEEmargins`. It would appear that you failed to set one or more options that should have been passed to the `IEEEtran` document class. Just out of curiosity: Do you get any error mesages when you compile the file on your system? Separately so try to fix the causes of the warning messages about multiply-defined labels.

Comment: Also, double-check that `conference` is the option you want as it is apparently unknown. This does not necessarily mean it really is unknown, but it does mean you need to be really sure it is known.

Comment: In addition to showing the reams and reams from the log file, it would be  helpful if you posted the preamble of the document you're trying to submit online.

Comment: The International Journal of Information Securit runs uploaded files with `\write18`  enabled? There must be a joke somewhere, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: @Mico I have uploaded the preamble.

Comment: If I augment your document (e.g, `\begin{document} Hello. \end{document}` to make it compilable, I unfortunately cannot compile it successfully. E.g., how and where is `\overrideIEEEmargins` defined? Are you maybe using a custom version of the `IEEEconf.cls` document class file? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I have downloaded the Latex-package.zip from the springer website and edited it. \overrideIEEEmargins I am not having any idea about this.

Comment: The compilation on the journal system is being done with the IEEEconf.cls from TeXLive 2015.  Does that match the class you use on your local system?

Comment: Also you could just remove the two `override` commands from your own preamble.

Comment: @Simranjeet - You wrote, "I have downloaded the Latex-package.zip from the springer website". I wasn't aware that Springer distributes IEEEtran-related files.